# How to return from a Javascript funtion without calling return?

Tags: javascript, call

I'm trying to simplify a line of code I do use everytime:

```
if (we_need_to_exit) { op(); return; }
```

Do I have a chance to define a function, something like this:

```
function my_return (x) {
  x.op();
  x.return; 
}
```

and use it like:

```
if (we_need_to_exit) { my_return(this); }
```

Is it possible to define such a function?

## Edit

Best simple solution that fits [in my case](https://github.com/ceremcem/livescript-examples/blob/ff708b5ef3c63578247f418e6970ab233605d0fb/multi-thread-sequential-events.ls#L55) is the following:

```
if (we_need_to_exit) { return op(); }
```

Comment: In short, you can't.

Comment: No. If you call a function, return in it will only return its response to caller. You can try `return my_return(this)`

Comment: What do you mean by `x.return` ? Are you trying to access `return` property of `x` object ? There is no as such restriction to have a `return` statement in the function..Unless you want use the value being manipulated in the function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, once you call `my_return`, that `return` inside of `my_return` is to return from within `my_return`.

You can probably do what you want by:

```
if (we_need_to_exit) { return my_fn(this); }
```

and your `my_fn` will be:

```
function my_fn (x) {
  x.op();
  // return any value you want, or use "return;" or just omit it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this won't work:

```
function my_return (x) {
  x.op();
  x.return; //[1] [2]
}

//-----and use it like-------------------

if (we_need_to_exit) { my_return(this); //[3]}
```

1. It means creating a return property on x, it won't return.
2. replacing `x.return;` with `return;` will return from the function, not from outside of it's call (at [3], which is your objective).
3. 'my_return(this)' "this" will be set to the object calling the function the "if statement" is in.

   ```
   function x(){
     console.log(this); //shows the global object (window, if run in a browser)
   }    
   var y = {
     fruit:"apple",
     x:function(){
         console.log(this); // shows the calling object
       }
   };
   x();
   y.x();
   ```